# unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) - Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, rspec-rails

> **Note:** selenium-webdriver (2.24.0), Mozilla Firefox 45.0.2, rails (3.2.19), ruby (1.8.7)

**customer_request.rb**

```
  before(:each) do
     @srtuser = login_as(:customer)
  end

  after(:each) do

  end

  def login_as(role)
    u = User.where(:email => "testing@test.net").first
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "user[email]", :with => u.email
    fill_in "user[password]", :with => "changeme"
    click_button "Sign in"
    page.should have_content("#{u.visible_name}")
    u
  end
```

> **ERROR:**   Failure/Error: visit new_user_session_path
>        Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
>          unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
>        # ./spec/requests/customer_spec.rb:37:in `login_as'
>        # ./spec/requests/customer_spec.rb:28

i tried downgrade and upgrade firefox didnt get any success